# Taskbar icon disappears when minimizing form application c#

Tags: c#, desktop-application

When I'm changing windows(forms), my application's icon disappears from taskbar. So for opening the application, users need to click ALT+TAB to select the form which is hidden from taskbar. After users choose application, icon comes to taskbar again. I don't want my applcation icon disappears from taskbar.

My codes are below:

```
//Program.cs
[STAThread]
static void Main()
{
    Application.Run(new LoginPage());
}
```

Login Page is application's first screen that gets username and password. After clicking submit button application is going to main page.

```
//LoginPage.cs  
private void submitBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MainPage mainPage= new MainPage();                   
    mainPage.Show();
    this.Hide();
}
```

Lets say I have a button on main page for going to another form. Here when I click the page1 button taskbar icon disappears.

```
//MainPage.cs
private void page1Btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Page1 page1 = new Page1();
    page1.Show();
    this.Hide();
}
```

After some research I found one solution for that but there is another problem which I cannot minimize the form correctly.

When I change the codes above with below

```
//MainPage.cs
private void page1Btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Page1 page1= new Page1();
    page1.ShowInTaskbar = false;
    page1.Owner = this;
    page1.ShowDialog();
    this.Hide();     
}
```

Here, I also need to modify Page1 as below

```
//Page1.cs
private void Page1_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
{
    MainPage mainPage = new MainPage();
    mainPage.Show();
}
```

Here I can successfully go to page1 step by step (without disappearing the taskbar icon). When I minimize the page1, it minimizes the application as expected but when I maximize the application from taskbar, I expect Page1 should maximizes but MainPage maximizes with an minimized Page one like below image.

[image: MainPage]

I only want to correct these problems. I hope there is experts which experienced these things there.

Comment: Dont hide the form!

Comment: There is another problem on that case. MainPage should be hidden for user experience.

Comment: Thats then a design issue - but the reason it goes from the bar is you are hiding the main form.

Comment: i suggest to use [MDI forms](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3553/Introduction-to-MDI-Forms-with-C) [How To USE](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-4EYhC9xDHo) it is a professional and pretty cool thing

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but as I can see MDI container opens the new form inside of the parent. This is not suitable for me. The pages are irrelevant. I think you suggest this with looking the image that I shared. The menu item is not exist at Page1

Comment: @BugFinder without hiding the MainPage how can I go to Page1 and hide MainPage? In my case, if user opens Page1, I dont want from him to turn MainPage before closing Page1. Thats why I'm hiding it. On the other hand, I'm hiding the MainPage but after that showing another form, why other one also disappears from taskbar? It makes no sense to me.

Comment: Your main form is exactly that.  Why would you need to hide it? Its not forms that show on the task bar, but apps, and what you see is largely governed by the main form. Hide it, it hides from the task bar so you can do things like have it in the systray

Comment: You are wrong. Hiding is not disappears the form. You can try. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is solved.

The problem was, I was maximizing the form from properties of the page.

Instead of maximizing it from properties, I do it manually from Page Load and its solved.

```
this.Bounds = Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea;
```

Answer (score 0):

In MetroFramework, I have the same problem. When my application starts (in the FORM_LOAD) , I programmatically maximize and the icon disappears. Checking the MetroFramework code, the problem is caused by ShadowType. If you change the ShadowType to None:

```
this.ShadowType= MetroFormShadowType.None;
```

the issue is resolved. I hope the solution works